# How can I use decodable in unspecified return data from API

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, decodable

when trying to parse return data from API im getting "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." because the return is inconsistent.

When logo_url has value it was a object see example below:

```
"logo_url": {
                    "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
                    "url": "http://google.com"
                },
```

But when it doenst have value its return empty array

```
"logo_url": [],
```

This is the reason why im getting "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

My model

```
struct Model: Decodable {
    let logo: Logo?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case logo = "logo_url"
    }
}

struct Logo: Decodable {
    
    let mimeType: String?
    let url: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mimeType = "mime_type"
        case url
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix the API if you can - `logo_url` should either always be a (possibly empty) array or a (possibly null) object.  If you can't change the API you will need to write custom decoder code

Comment: Unrelated, but it's better to make `url` be a type of `URL` instead of `String`.

Comment: @Paulw11 i have no control on doing the API side of it. can i have a sample custom decoder? im not sure how to do it.

Comment: @NewDev i cant make it String because its returning the url without the baseUrl. i just make it complete in thats example thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change this badly written API, you'd need a custom decoder, where you basically attempt to decode as the type you want, and failing that - make it `nil`:

```
struct Model: Decodable {
    let logo: Logo?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case logo = "logo_url"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        if let logo = try? container.decode(Logo.self, forKey: .logo) {
            self.logo = logo
        } else {
            self.logo = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer checking if the `logo_url` is an array first, then let Swift report error if there is any happens by using `try` instead of `try?` when trying to decode a key. Since in most cases, you may want to know why your decoding failed instead of just getting `nil` as a result.

Additionally, you may want to use `.convertFromSnakeCase` as a `keyDecodingStrategy` so you don't have to write extra code.

```
let json2 = """
{
  "logo_url": {
    "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
    "url": "http://google.com"
  }
}
"""

let json3 = "[]"

struct Logo: Decodable {
  let mimeType: String
  let url: String
}

struct Model: Decodable {
  let logo: Logo?

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case logoUrl
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if (try? container.decode([String].self, forKey: .logoUrl)) != nil {
      self.logo = nil
    } else {
      self.logo = try container.decode(Logo.self, forKey: .logoUrl)
    }
  }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

let result2 = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: json2.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(result2)

let result3 = try? decoder.decode(Model.self, from: json3.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(result3)
```